# Java how to get path of picture on .jar

Tags: java, path, png

I want to get the picture path in .jar. I have opened my app (.jar) as a winrar, and I found my picture, but path of this file not works:

```
BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("/windows.png"));
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
```

[Image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM5oo.jpg)

[Image winrar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llCzp.jpg)

It means it works in IntelliJ IDEA but not as app.
So what is this file path(as app, not IDE)?
Thanks for help and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SomeTextFile.txt");
```

You can find more detailed answer eg. here [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)